# I want to update a specific record which is edited in list of records

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

When i am updating a record all the records in the list also gets updated. I only want the record which changes should only update not others in the list.

This is the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="CustPageEditCtrl">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!custList}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.id}"/>
        <apex:column headervalue="First Name">
        <apex:inputtext value="{!c.First_Name__c}" label="First Name"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Last Name">
        <apex:inputtext value="{!c.Last_Name__c}" label="Last Name"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Click to update">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!UpdateCustomer}" value="UpdateCustomer"/>
        </apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>
<br/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!SaveCustList}" value="SaveCustList"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is the controller.

```
 public class CustPageEditCtrl {

    public List<Customer__c> custList{get; set;}

    public CustPageEditCtrl (){
        custList = [SELECT id, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c FROM Customer__c];
    }

    public PageReference SaveCustList() {
        update custList;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference UpdateCustomer() {

        for (Integer i = 0; i<custList.size(); i++) {
            update custList.get(i);
        }

        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://burnignorance.com/salesforce-tips/multiple-row-editing-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a page parameter for this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!UpdateCustomer}" value="UpdateCustomer" reRender="form">
  <apex:param name="recordId" value="{!c.id}" assignTo="{!rowId}" />
</apex:commandButton>
```

*Edit:* The "reRender" attribute is required for the apex:param to work correctly if you use this technique.

---

```
public static Id rowId { get; set; }
...
public void UpdateCustomer() {
    for (Integer i = 0; i<custList.size(); i++) {
        if(rowId == custList[i].Id) {
            update custList[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'd actually use a slightly more efficient method in this case:

```
public void UpdateCustomer() {
    update new Map<Id, Customer__c>(custList).get(rowId);
}
```

Which allows us to find the record by Id using a map.

---

## Alternative Method

You can actually make a "wrapper class" that will encapsulate the record, which also allows you to know which record to update:

```
public class CustPageEditCtrl {
    public class Wrapper {
        public Customer__c record { get; set; }
        public Wrapper(Customer__c rec) {
            record = rec;
        }
        public void save() {
            update record;
        }
    }
    public List<Wrapper> custList{get; set;}
    Customer__c[] recordList { get; set; }

    public CustPageEditCtrl() {
        custList = new Wrapper[0];
        recordList = [SELECT id, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c FROM Customer__c];
        for(Customer__c record: recordList) {
            custList.add(new Wrapper(record));
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

This requires you to rewrite your page code as well:

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!custList}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.record.id}"/>
        <apex:column headervalue="First Name">
        <apex:inputtext value="{!c.record.First_Name__c}" label="First Name"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Last Name">
        <apex:inputtext value="{!c.record.Last_Name__c}" label="Last Name"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Click to update">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!c.save}" value="UpdateCustomer"/>
        </apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!UpdateCustomer}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page custpageedit: Class.CustPageEditCtrl.UpdateCustomer: line 17, column 1

Comment: @FireFly Yeah, it looks like you need to add a reRender attribute to the save button to work correctly.

Comment: thanks for your help rerender attribute is working. now only record which is changed only gets updated.

Comment: @FireFly You're welcome! I also included an alternative if you want to look at it as well.

Comment: For sure! i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many fundamentals of Salesforce custom development, especially about Apex and DB Interaction. So you going through relevant trial module and/or guide would really help.

Coming to question here, there are two issues I think.

1. When you call updateCustomer(), I think yo are looking to just make a note that of new data in memory and don't actually update to db.

But in the code you are actually dating to db. What you would want to do is, create second list (which would be empty when you start) and add to that list each time you updateCustomer.

2. When you call saveCustList, check the new list and if it is not empty, call update on that list.